# x-editable trigger in angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

Frankly i need an auto focus next field in angularjs xeditable form. It's also available in jQuery xeditable form [Exactly like this](http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/templates/admin3/form_editable.html)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks.......! but @Peter can u understand my question....

Comment: @Peter there is no need for sample code... i need when i completely entered one xeditable field, it automatically triggers the another one.(like auto focus next field) plz check the link........!

Comment: can u solve this issue........@Peter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add x-editable auto-open next field feature in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025359/add-x-editable-auto-open-next-field-feature-in-angularjs)

Comment: that's also me...... check the asked user.....

Comment: Yes, its the same 'question' as well.

Comment: that's not mandatory.... ! help me for trigger.....